# Flash of unstyled content when doing router.refresh in Nextjs13

Tags: next.js, next.js13, fouc

Nextjs 13 at least at one point recommended using `router.refresh()` to mutate data and revalidate if you let the user for example click a button in a client component that changes some data.

When I do this, the entire page flashes its unstyled content as the fonts are re-downloaded. I implement fonts in the official way, using `next/font/google`. How do I avoid this FOUC? I've read that server actions act like an even bigger refresh, so they wouldn't work, would they?

Comment: I suspect that you see this issue in development mode? Does this also occur in a production build?

Answer (score 1):

This bug was fixed and reintroduced multiple times in the last several months. The bug is currently fixed for me on Next 14.1.

Here's the most recent mention of the bug that I was able to find on their GitHub:

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/60175

Comment: I hate Nextjs so much nowadays. I don't know what to do.